# Flutter mockito with null safety throws Null type error

Tags: flutter, mockito, flutter-test

I've been having this issue for a while following the official docs on mocking.

This test when run throws an error `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

[image: Test with error]

When I change from `String` to `String?` on `getString()` it passes and I don't understand why. I have no intention for the function to ever be null so I don't need to make it nullable.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using mockito null safety you have to do there:

1. You need to add @GenerateMocks(["M"]) before main(), where "M" will be the name of the class that you want to create a Mock, and you have to delete 'class MMock extends Mock implements M'

```
@GenerateMocks(["M"])
void main() {....}
```

2. Then you need to import "import package:mockito/annotations.dart';"
3. Next you have to install 'build_runner: ^1.11.0' in your dev dependencies, and finally you have to run the command: "flutter pub run build_runner build", that will create a Mock file which you have to use instead of MMock, the name would be 'Mockclassname'

You can know more in this link:
https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md

or this video (this in spanish)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWs3gfYF5u8

Comment: Yeah this worked. An alternative way is to use the mocktail class, it allows stubbing null safe code without auto-generating.